# Convert spark dataframe to Delta table on azure databricks - warning

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am saving my spark dataframe on azure databricks and create delta lake table.

It works fine, however I am getting this warning message while execution.

Question- Why I am still getting this message, even with my table is delta table. What is wrong with my approach, any inputs is greatly appreciated.

**Warning Message**

> This query contains a highly selective filter. To improve the performance of queries, convert the table to Delta and run the OPTIMIZE ZORDER BY command on the table

**Code**

```
dfMerged.write\
              .partitionBy("Date")\
              .mode("append")\
              .format("delta")\
              .option("overwriteSchema", "true")\
              .save("/mnt/path..")

spark.sql("CREATE TABLE DeltaUDTable USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/path..'")
```

Some more details

1. I've mounted azure storage gen 2 to above mount location.
2. databricks runtime - 6.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)

Comment: think the warning message is misleading

Comment: thanks @thebluephantom for your inputs, that's what I thought so. I will go ahead and close this post.

Comment: @thebluephantom Would you like to post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Ok, that is cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning message is clearly misleading as you already have a Delta option. Ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

we can save the dataframe as delta table direcly using below code block

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("table_loc")
```